# why can't I render component from inside .map in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I want to display some components based on the data I got from an api using `fetch`. when I tried to debug it using `console.log`, it has a value but the component won't show.. what am I doing wrong here?

MasterRute.js

```
const MasterRute = () => {
  const [rute, setRute] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getRute();
  }, []);

  const getRute = async (query='') => {
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8080/rute');
    const data = await response.json();
    setRute(data);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {
        rute.map((item, index) => {
          if (index == 0) {
            console.log(index, item.nama_rute); // 0 Lorem
            (<div>{item.nama_rute}</div>)
          }
        })
      }
    </div>
  );

}
```

any help is appreciated

Comment: You don't seem to be returning anything from the .map(...)!

Comment: @siddarth Seth I thought `(<div>{item.nama_rute}</div>)` already does that?

Comment: Try adding a return statement and let us know if it works now...

Comment: oh I see. it works now after I changed it into `return (<div>{item.nama_rute}</div>)`. thank you! my knowledge of JSX is really crappy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's break down this return statement:

```
return (
    <div>
      {
        rute.map((item, index) => {
          if (index == 0) {
            console.log(index, item.nama_rute); // 0 Lorem
            (<div>{item.nama_rute}</div>)
          }
        })
      }
    </div>
  );
```

Loosely speaking, we can see that you're returning "a div element with some piece of JS inside it". Here's the "JS inside your div":

```
rute.map((item, index) => {
  if (index == 0) {
     console.log(index, item.nama_rute); // 0 Lorem
     (<div>{item.nama_rute}</div>)
  }
})
```

Now let's break this down. You have a .map() on an array that is supposed to accept a function that takes (item, index) and returns a value for that item and index.

But is this actually happening?

```
if (index == 0) {
  console.log(index, item.nama_rute);
  (<div>{item.nama_rute}</div>)
}
```

it's logging the value, but it isn't returning anything!
the `(<div>...</div>)` might as well just be another `console.log` statement.

Try this:

```
if (index == 0) {
  console.log(index, item.nama_rute);
  return <div>{item.nama_rute}</div>;
} else {
  return <div>Not supported yet</div>
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks. I didn't know we can use `return` statement in jsx. I thought the `()` braces already does that

Comment: all good! yeah the trick is that your return statement is inside the map() function, not the JSX

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can use `if` statement inside jsx, try this :

```
return (
    <div>
      {rute.map((item, index) => (<>{index === 0 && <div>{item.nama_rute}</div></>}))}
    </div>
);
```

Comment: after some experiments I've found out that we *can* use `if` inside jsx. although the brackets will get really messy and confusing